# how to select an option in select tag by hitting the first letter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select tag in html, with 5 options as following :- "Bangalore", "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Hyderabad", "Pune". When the user type 'B' in keyboard it should show 'Bangalore' , when the user type 'D', it should show Delhi, as like the others also, when the user type the first letter of the options, it should show the corresponding options. How I do it in html .

Comment: It already does that. You have to be specific what exactly you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (HTML5)

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Please,mark it as correct, if you're problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "Bangalore",
  "Mumbai",
  "Delhi",
  "Hyderabad",
  "Pune"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
 </head>
<body>

 <div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input list="city">
        <datalist id="city">
        <option value="Bangalore">
        <option value="Mumbai">
        <option value="Delhi">
        <option value="Hyderabad">
        <option value="Pune">
    </datalist>
```

```html
<input list="city">
    <datalist id="city">
    <option value="Bangalore">
    <option value="Mumbai">
    <option value="Delhi">
    <option value="Hyderabad">
    <option value="Pune">
</datalist>
```